# Grep a result from Hive output log

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have an output from Hive. I stored that output in a variable called `match`.

I am isolating the line I need from the log using the command below.

```
echo $(echo $match | grep "COUNT_TOTAL_MATCH")

0: jdbc:hive2://hiveaddress> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .> +--------------------+-------+--+ | stats | _c1 | +--------------------+-------+--+ | COUNT_TOTAL_MATCH | 1000 | +--------------------+-------+--+ 0: jdbc:hive2://hiveaddress> 0: jdbc:hive2://hiveaddress>
```

How do I grab the `1000` value knowing it could be any other number?

Comment: what is your grep version? does it support `-P`?

Comment: Grep 2.6.3. It supports `-P`

Comment: also, I would suggest `echo "$match" | grep 'COUNT_TOTAL_MATCH'` instead of your code... [quote variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters/131767#131767) and use single quotes unless you need it to be interpreted by shell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
grep -oP 'COUNT_TOTAL_MATCH\h*\|\h*\K\d+'
```

- `\h*\|\h*` optional space/tab followed by `|` followed by optional space/tab
- `\K` is positive lookbehind... so only if `COUNT_TOTAL_MATCH\h*\|\h*` is matched

  - `\d+` get digits

From `man grep`

```
   -o, --only-matching
          Print  only  the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output
          line.

   -P, --perl-regexp
          Interpret  the pattern as a Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE).  This is highly experimental and
          grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can treat  `|`  (space pipe space) as the field delimiter and print the sixth field, like this:

```
awk -F ' \\| ' '{ print $6 }'
```

Notice that the pipe [has to be escaped twice](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps).

---

Side note:

```
echo $(echo $match | grep "COUNT_TOTAL_MATCH")
```

can be rewritten as

```
grep 'COUNT_TOTAL_MATCH' <<< "$match"
```

No `echo`, no pipes, and no word splitting in `$match`. `echo "$(command)"` is always the same as just `command`. (Notice that quoting makes a difference, though.)

This means that you can combine your grep and awk commands into this:

```
awk -F ' \\| ' '/COUNT_TOTAL_MATCH/ { print $6 }' <<< "$match"
```